# Pass typename as parameter with operator()

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Consider the following code:

```
struct S {
    ...
    template<typename T>
    T operator() {
        ...
    }
};
```

This can only be called using:

```
s.operator()<Foo>();
```

Is there a way the typename can be inferred by passing a parameter such as:

```
s(Foo);
```

instead?

Comment: The only way I can think of would involve preprocessor hackery, which comes with all sorts of unwanted side-effects since the preprocessor does not honour scope.   Since I don't support usage of preprocessor solutions as a solution to avoiding typing by the programmer, given something like this, I would simply change the name of the function  (e.g. to `get()` instead of `operator()` and live with the calling syntax  `s.get<Foo>()`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the type in a templated tag type struct:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t { };
template<class T> tag_t<T> tag{};

struct S {
  template<class T>
  T operator()( tag_t<T> );
} s;

s( tag<Foo> );
```

Comment: @super `s(tag<Foo>{})`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
struct S {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(const T&) { }
} s;

struct Foo {};

Foo foo;
s (foo);
```

Is that close enough to what you want?

Comment: Alternatively, you can call that like this: `s (Foo{});` so you don't need an explicit temporary variable.

Comment: require a copy constructible type (as you pass by copy) and an instance (which might be expensive/complex to construct).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it might be better to use `void operator()(const T&)`

Comment: Answer changed accordingly.